# Micro front-end application using Single SPA

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

All - We are planning to migrate our UI to micro-front end as architecturally we are having increasing count of Spring-Boot related services at the back end layer level.

Single UI codebase consuming multiple boot services creates UI dependency and UI codebase becoming single point of failure. To overcome this and to consume UI + Data wherever we wish to, thinking to implement micro-frontend apps for UI and to migrate our current setup as well.

When we looked at, we could see single-spa framework helps us on this. PoC is also positive. Would like to understand if there any constraints related to this approach, caveats, pros/cons etc. Please advise if someone across about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try building Micro Frontend using Web Components approach

Benefits:

1. Easy to run as a standalone application as well as into cross framework
2. use webpack to bundle the MFE into single js file
3. Use GZIP to reduce the bundle size
4. Custom elements define approach

*Hope this helps. let me know if you any further detail into this*

Comment: Thanks suraj. What is the advantage over the single spa. My understanding is it is readly available framework. We can use Single SPA for faster development and they have community support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build a micro frontend architecture using the [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/).
Lerna will help you for managing multi-package repositories in a single repo.

Example :

```
packages
 - main-app
 - feature-based-apps
    - feature-01-app
    - feature-02-app
    - feature-03-app
    - feature-04-app
    - feature-05-app
    ...
 - shared-utils
```

Benefits:

- Allows scaling development teams
- Simplify updates
- Independent deploy

Answer (score 0):

**Memory Cost.**
When you are using Openshift or other platform services, **you should book CPU and memory size for each your MF(micro-frontend)**. This is will make your app grow bigger time after time. Because each MF running on each server.